# In C++ why have va_start immediately followed by va_end?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I see the following code in a few functions in a project I am trying to read and understand:

```cpp
void Algo::descend(const enc_node* node, const char* option, ...)
{
    ...
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, option);
    va_end(va);
    ...
}
```

I understand variadic functions in principle but why would someone make a variadic function and then call `va_start()` followed immediately by `va_end()` with nothing in between? What does this achieve?

Comment: Why would you use a variadic function in C++?  This is a serious question: it seems the whole point of C++ is to avoid things such as this from C.  If you're going to use a variadic function, it seems to me you might as well be using C.

Comment: Doesn't look like it  does anything useful to me. Could simply be someone was mindlessly applying boiler plate. Could be they started writing the function, got called into a meeting, reassigned to a different task, and didn't notice they hadn't finished the function when they got back to it.

Comment: The code you show, will just ignore any parameters beyond `option`, hard to tell why the author decided to do this. Either it's wrong, or intentional for some reason. Impossible to tell without having more context. Can you tell where you found that, and what this function is supposed to do please?

Comment: Yeah that seems lazy to just catch extra arguments without doing anything with them. The function can be found [here](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265/blob/master/libde265/encoder/algo/algo.cc#L42) (also in the ascend function below it). The project is H265 video coding and I am not certain exactly what this function does but it seems like it keeps track of what level in the coding tree the encoder is at

Comment: @WilliamPursell "*Why would you use a variadic function in C++?*" - either the author didn't know any better, or is targeting pre-C++11 compilers that don't have variadic templates available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In C++ why have va_start immediately followed by va_end?

No idea.

> why would someone make a variadic function and then call va_start() followed immediately by va_end() with nothing in between?

No idea, that doesn't make much sense. It's like writing `int a;` and never using that variable. (Probably a sign of not enough coffee in programmers mind.)

> What does this achieve?

Nothing.

---

The full function that you posted a link to gives more insight:

```
void Algo::descend(const enc_node* node, const char* option, ...)
{
  if (logdebug_enabled(LogEncoder)) {
    descendLevel++;
    printf("%d ",descendLevel);
    for (int i=0;i<descendLevel;i++) { printf(" "); }

    va_list va;
    va_start(va, option);
    va_end(va);

    fprintf(stdout, ">%s(", name());
    vfprintf(stdout, option, va);
    fprintf(stdout, ") %d;%d %dx%d %p\n",node->x,node->y,1<<node->log2Size,1<<node->log2Size,node);
  }
}
```

The function is invalid as all other such functions in [the link you mentioned](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265/blob/master/libde265/encoder/algo/algo.cc#L42). Calling `vfprintf` and using `va` after `va_end` is undefined behavior. If it's an open project - help the community and notify the developer.

Comment: Yeah it's a mistake, but on most platforms, `va_end()` expands to nothing so you don't notice it.

Comment: I didn't post the full code because I was specifically interested in why someone would have `va_start()` followed immediately by `va_end()`. Not asking for an analysis of this super specific function but just a general note about why someone would do this in c++. If there is no reason and it is a mistake that is all I needed to know

Comment: To answer a question like "Why?" one has to know the context of the actions, to discover the reasoning behind those actions that lead to answer. Here an answer to "why?" is simple after knowing the function - looks like the programmer made a mistake.

Comment: Understood. I'll be sure to post the full function for context in the future. Thanks

Comment: @thehumaneraser working in collective that generates such artefacts on hourly basis, I'll say: it's boilerplate misuse. They copy-pasted `va_list va; va_start(va, option); va_end(va);` and then pasted rest of code after, because they didn't knew better or were doing this repeatedly for various functions (perhaps at the end of work day,  "the Friday commit rule" applies). While it's UB , with mst implementations it doesn't break.